# Sending XMLHttpRequest and information server not to send any acknowlegment

Tags: javascript, ajax, html

I'm very much new to JavaScript and AJAX world.

I have some code which create XMLHttpRequest() object, send request to server and later receive the response from the server, as per my understanding.

I only want to send some information to server and don't want to receive any response from the server even if the information is reached at all to the server.

So is there any ***standard mechanism/protocol*** by which we can inform the server that I don't need response from you, so don't waste your time in doing so.

Comment: XMLHttpRequests are sent over HTTP. All HTTP requests have responses. The responses can be empty (apart from response code and headers), but they are still sent. Would it just suffice to ignore the response?

Comment: So make a head request and ignore the response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send data to the server - jQuery.ajax({option}).

In the options part, you can send data to the server. Just send a flag. On server, read the flag, and if it has a particular value, just don't return anything.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I was also thinking the same. Moreover, I am also writing the server thing too.

Comment: @dearvivekkumar No problem, but as the other guys mentioned, there is always a response, you're just ignoring it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

HTTP doesn't consider any case where you make a request and don't get a response.

You can make a HEAD request (so long as you would otherwise GET data) to ask the server to return only meta data instead of the complete body.

You would probably be best setting the server to return a minimal acknowledgement though.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json

true
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely sure why you don't want to receive a response from the server. I have many Ajax requests on my site, and many of them do not *require* a response. However, I still listen for a response so that I know that the request was successful. As far as I know, there is no standard way to "fire and forget" an Ajax request, but you can always just send the request and not look back.